# Example of open cover of (0,1) which has no finite subcover

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Give an example of an open cover of the segment $(0,1)$ which has no finite subcover.

**Example:** Taking $G_n=(0,1-1/n)$ for $n>1$. It is obvious that $(0,1)\subset \cup_{n=2}^{\infty}G_n$ but $\{G_n\}$ has no finite subcover of $(0,1)$.

Does this example satisfy the conditions of problem?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This is shown as a first question in the list of related questions (in the sidebar on the right): [Cover of (0,1) with no finite subcover & Open sets of compact function spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257514/cover-of-0-1-with-no-finite-subcover-open-sets-of-compact-function-spaces)